# Select a table with multiple columns according to IN clause

Tags: mysql

I've a query

```
SELECT t1.user,t1.answer as 'Q1',t2.answer as 'Q2'
from 
(select answer,user from survey_answer where question_id=45) t1
JOIN
(select answer,user from survey_answer where question_id=46) t2
ON
t1.user=t2.user
```

In this the `question_id` i.e. 45,46,47,48,...etc. is in hundreds
the number on join increases number of columns as q1,q2,q3... so on...

like :

```
________________________
user | q1 | q2 | q4 | q5
------------------------
1    | ok | yes|    | no
------------------------
2    |    | yes| no |
```

Is there a way to form the query using IN(45,46,47,....) or use loop in procedure/function...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a column for each answer you can use group_concat() to build a single string with all answers per user.

```
drop table if exists survey_answer;
create table if not exists survey_answer(user int, question_id int, answer varchar(200));
insert into survey_answer values
(1,60,'answer 1'),
(1,61,'answer 2'),
(1,62,'answer 3'),
(2,61,'answer 4'),
(2,52,'answer 5'),
(3,40,'answer 6'),
(3,62,'answer 7'),
(4,61,'answer 8'),
(4,62,'answer 9'),
(4,10,'answer 10'),
(4,32,'answer 11');

select distinct(t1.user), 
       (select group_concat(t2.answer, ',')
        from survey_answer t2
        where t2.user = t1.user) answers
from survey_answer t1
;

drop table if exists survey_answer;
```

This is the result:

```
| user | answers                                   |
|------|-------------------------------------------|
| 1    | answer 1,,answer 2,,answer 3,             |
| 2    | answer 4,,answer 5,                       |
| 3    | answer 6,,answer 7,                       |
| 4    | answer 8,,answer 9,,answer 10,,answer 11, |
```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/MME71460)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer But I was looking the answers to be in different columns...

so that I could have the table's column name which u have above as _user,answers_ to be the `question_text` in another table with primary key question_id which is foreign key in current table (survey_answer) we are looking at.

I found pivot but it is not built into MySQL people are doing it through procedures...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table. There's no built in `PIVOT` syntax in MySQL, but the following should work well enough (though it will not be fun to write):

```
SELECT
    user,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN question_id = 60 THEN answer ELSE 0 END) AS ans60,
    SUM(CASE WHEN question_id = 61 THEN answer ELSE 0 END) AS ans61,
    SUM(CASE WHEN question_id = 193234 THEN answer ELSE 0 END) AS ans193234,
FROM 
    survey_answer
GROUP BY 
    user
```

If you have dynamic number of columns or a large number of columns, [dynamic SQL can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(question_id = ''',question_id,''',answer,NULL)) AS ans',question_id)
              ) INTO @sql
FROM survey_answer;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT user, 
       ', @sql, ' 
FROM 
    survey_answer
GROUP BY 
    user');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem over here is that the `question_id` will be in hundreds and will be input from user in runtime.

Comment: @GarvitJain: See edit. You can use dynamic SQL to do this in a procedure or script.